# Adding count to a df produced by a group-by cut

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

Neither `.size()` nor `.count()` seem to produce a single count column when
applied to data produced with a `.cut()` method.

This may only be a problem of syntax, but I have tried `.size()`, `.count()`, and `.describe()` and get multiple columns with a group count, but not 1 single column.

```
#python 2.7
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(seed=1)
df = pd.DataFrame({"var1": np.random.random(100), 
                   "var2": np.random.random(100) + 5})

# Bin the data frame by "var1" with 10 bins...
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.var1, 10)).describe().var2[['mean','count']]
df =df.reset_index()
print df"

#Results:
                     var1      mean  count
0  (-0.000874, 0.099]  5.546257   11.0
1      (0.099, 0.198]  5.434613   12.0
2      (0.198, 0.297]  5.483686    9.0
3      (0.297, 0.396]  5.313241    6.0
4      (0.396, 0.494]  5.537168   13.0
5      (0.494, 0.593]  5.518476   10.0
6      (0.593, 0.692]  5.614630   10.0
7      (0.692, 0.791]  5.443415   10.0
8       (0.791, 0.89]  5.464804    7.0
9       (0.89, 0.989]  5.418756   12.0
```

#Updated the posted question with code that provides the desired answer.

Comment: Not sure what you need

Comment: I want to add a column "cnt' to the df that shows the number of items in each bin that were used to compute the mean value shown as "var2".

Answer (score 2):

If that is case you need `transform` with `pd.Series.groupby()`

```
df['cnt']=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.var1, 10))['var2'].transform('count')
```